# Организация структуры таблиц

Tags: база-данных, mysql, sql

Подскажите как лучше организовать хранение данных:
Есть следующая информация о тракторах:
- вид трактора (Колёсный трактор,Гусеничный трактор,Сельскохозяйственный трактор..)
- производитель трактора ( СПК, КПП, МНК)..
- модель трактора (Т-28Х4,МТЗ-80) в зависимости от производителя трактора..у каждого производителя свой модельный ряд.
- режим работы трактора (а,б,с)

Любой из видов тракторов может выпускаться любым из производителей
У конкретного производителя могут быть только уникальные модели тракторов,не выпускаемые другими производителями.
И режимы работы стандартизированы для любых моделей.
Что скажете насчет структуры? каков вариант лучше?
 Между таблицами tractor_types и tractor_producers устанавливаю связь (многие ко многим)
 Но в тоже время tractor_producers связан с tractor_models (модельным рядом) отношением (один ко многим) и tractor_models с operation ( режимом работы) (один к одному, или один ко многим).. 
 Подскажите пожалуйста с организацией структуры.

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с начала.

Есть таблица **ПроизводителиТракторов**.

Есть таблица **МоделиТракторов**.

Если точно, ни при каких обстоятельствах одну модель не могут делать два прозиводителя (ну или это будет все равно разная маркировка, если даже одинаково технически), тогда в **МоделиТракторов** можно делать ссылку на **ПроизводителиТракторов**. Если 100% уверенности нет, то лучше сделать таблицу сцепку **ВыпускаемыеМодели** в которой будет ссылка на **МоделиТракторов** и на **ПроизводителиТракторов**.

В каждой МоделиТракторов, есть ссылка на **ВидТракторов** - ну, так как трактор не может быть одновременно колесным и гусенечным. Если может - делаете ещё одну сцепку.

Если режими работы у каждого свои - тогда делаете таблицу **РежимыРаботы**, где есть ссылка на трактор. А скорее всего тут нужна будет сцепка, так как **РежимовРаботы** не сильно много и они пересекаются для разных **МоделейТракторов**.

Конечно немного неряшливая структура, но без уточнения предметной области сложно что-то оптимизировать. Если есть вопросы, как тут отбирать - жду))

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста в правильном ли направлении я двигаюсь :
1) Вид трактора и производитель связаны отношением многие ко многим.
 через дополнительную таблицу 
2) Далее связка производитель и модель.. один ко многим. В таблице моделей храню ид производителя.
3)Связка режимов работы и модели - один ко многим. в таблице моделей храню айди режима работы.
4) Тип трактора и модель трактора.. один ко многим. у каждой модели может быть один тип трактора тоесть в таблице модель храню  айди вида трактора. 
Нужна ли промежуточная таблица между типом трактора и производителем ?

Comment: Насчет режимов работы и моделями есть сомнение - не может ли быть много режимов у каждой модели?

Не вижу смысла в связи типа трактора и производителя. Тип - это аттрибут - модели. Если очень нужно, то получить типы, которые есть у производителя можно двумя join'ами... Кешировать это (хранить таблицу тип-производитель нужно только в том случае, если производителей много и такая инфа запрашивается частно - да и то не факт. возможно хватит кеша БД).

Связь много-много делается только через промежуточную таблицу.

Comment: действительно. может быть несколько режимов у каждой модели.. значит тогда эти две таблицы ( режимов и моделей) через промежуточную таблицу. верно?

Comment: Да. Через промежуточную.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. подскажите мне пожалуйста лучшую литературу и ресурсы по sql. Задачники. Новичку очень трудно разобраться на какую литературу лучше обратить внимание..

Comment: Практика + ковыряние чужих БД. Естественно больших и сложных. Правильному проектированию в книжках не учат. Можно почитать sql.ru - но именно почитать. Спрашивать там нужно вдумчиво и осторожно)

Answer (score 0):

Особо не вникал в задачу, но все же...

4 таблицы:

1. Модели - `t_model`(`id_model`,`id_manufaturer_fk`,`id_type_fk`,`id_mode_fk`)
2. Производители - `t_manufacturers`(`id_manufacturer`)
3. Виды - `t_types`(`id_type`)
4. Режимы - `t_modes`(`id_model`)

Таблицы 2-4 имеют связи к 1  - один ко многим. В таком случае у вас одна модель будет иметь принадлежать только 1му производителю, иметь только один вид и только один режим. В тоже время производитель может иметь много моделей. Один вид - ко многим моделям, один режим - ко многим моделям.